# iPhone lost all UI transition animation

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, user-interface

Currently I encounter an issue somehow, the application lost all those artistic UI animation for example, page flipping, alert view popup, action sheet slide up and etc. That means all those UI will show up immediately without any transition animation. It looked very weird.

Firstly, the app will run smoothly until something trigger the issue above, and after that only re-run the app or kill the app will stop the problem.

There is no error message or any clue that I can figure out what could be the reason. Have any one of you guy has encountered similar issue as above? Please share with me how am I able to solve the issue above. Thanks.

Comment: Are you testing the app on a simulator ?

Comment: yes… try to restart your MAC :)

Comment: Did you ever fix this bug?

Comment: @DavidvanDugteren No... The bug happen randomly, so it is very hard to track down the root cause. I believe that this bug mostly happen in old iPhone for example like, iPhone 4 and 4S. For latest iOS, I never encounter this issue anymore. My advice is that, be very careful, don't update any UI from background thread as this will have some serious impact for the app. Moreover, make sure there is no 'hanging' or 'loop-running' threads leaking in background as this will make the UI slow down (freeze) as well. Hope this helps.

Comment: Have the same issue. iPhone 6 plus(latest) with latest iOS, so not only old devices are exposed to

Answer (score 1):

Animations may get disabled for the entire app whenever an attempt is made to animate views on a background thread, e.g. by calling one of `UIView`'s `animateWithDuration:animations:` family of class methods from a background thread. Be sure to update your app's UI only from the main thread.

You can check if code is running on the main thread by testing `[NSThread currentThread].isMainThread` and you can ensure it runs on the main thread like so:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
    // Your code
});
```

Alternatively, ensure that you're not calling `[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO]` anywhere, as that will also disable animations for the entire app.